# RestKit: How to retry a failed request?

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm trying to make my app retry `RKRequests` if they fail. I'm trying to do it this way:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)errorIn
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.waitView stop];

    NSInteger code = objectLoader.response.statusCode;

    if (201 != code && 200 != code)
    {
        // determine whether to requeue the request or not

        if ([objectLoader.userData isEqualToString:@"capture"]) // requeue captures
        {
            NSLog(@"requeueing request");
            [objectLoader.queue cancelRequest:objectLoader];
            [objectLoader send];
        }
    }
}
```

... but it always crashes because `objectLoader` seems to be a dangling pointer after the `cancelRequest` line. If an `RKRequest` fails, how do I retry it without crashing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to access the RKRequest, e.g. using the RKRequestDelegate protocol:

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Because then you can just do the following:

```
NSAssert(!request.isUnsent && !request.isLoading, @"Cant retry load, current attempt has not completed");
[request reset];
[request send];
```

Comment: When I try this, the assert always goes off because request.isLoading is still set to true. If I comment out the assert, I get the "can't add the same request multiple times" error on [request send]. If I instead do [request sendAsynchronously], the request immediately fails. Why is it so difficult to get RestKit to do a simple retry?

Comment: Did you try to cancel the request manually? Then the assert should not fail.